# Why would this little python code cause memory leak?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks

```
def fun():
    n = 300
    features = [[0 for i in range(0, n)] for j in range(0, n)]  
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            features[i][j] = [np.random.random((300,300))]
    return

for i in range(10000):
    fun()
```

Featues is only local variables which should be collect after fun returns. Why this cause memory leak?

Comment: Why do you think there's a memory leak?

Comment: You can just try to run the code and see the memory consumption and you wil see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is storing 300 * 300 * 300 * 300 floats. At 8 bytes per float (the default for numpy floats) that is over 64 GB. I suspect that is why you are having memory problems.

That's not a memory leak though. Did you really mean to make a 4D beast matrix? If you just want 300 x 300, looks like `np.random.random((300, 300))` gives you that. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html#numpy.random.random